# Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\sessionHandler.php on
>   line 35

So this is what's on the line 35.

```
//to make a connection with database
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
```

I don't know whether this is the problem or the code I'm writing.
I have searched for every possible answer but it is not what I was looking for.

this is my code (if the problem is not really on the line 35)

```
//validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Input Validation
if($_POST['uname'] == '')
{
    $errmsg_arr[]='Login ID missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($_POST['pword'] == '')
{
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}


//if there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag)
{
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}

//to make a connection with database
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());


//to select the targeted database
mysql_select_db("ngchoonching", $conn) or die(mysql_error());

//to create a query to be executed in sql
$username = $_POST['uname'];
$password = $_POST['pword'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

//to run sql query in database
$result= mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

//check whether the query was successful or not
if(isset($result))
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        //Login successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['STATUS'] = true;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: login-successful.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        //login failed
        header("location: login-failed.html");
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    die("Query failed");
}

?>
```

I use localhost,phpmyadmin,xampp and I don't understand why the access is denied.

Comment: This is not a problem in the code, it's a problem with the database permissions. What does `show grants for root@localhost;` show?

Comment: Also avoid regular `mysql` use `mysqli` or better `PDO`

Comment: @Barmar it says `GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION` and `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: its possible with your current code todo a simple sql injection and just return a single row from your table and use that to authenticate even login as anyone. **Use mysqli or PDO with prepared query's**

Comment: @Barmar i'm sorry what should i do about this? This is actually my first time doing this, and i'm still learning

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try `$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root")` or `$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")`

Comment: it really work! thank you! but why do i have to remove the "password"? i just wanna know what difference does it make

Comment: Most likely because you didn't set a root password. In other words, your SQL setup is extremely, extremely vulnerable. [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-secure-mysql-and-mariadb-databases-in-a-linux-vps) has a lot of starting tips on securing it

Comment: Probably it's access privilege issue... try "select * from mysql.users" to see users who have passwords. for root in your case, password is probably empty...

If you set password later in your development process, just bring "password" parameter back.

Comment: @Rogue that sounds bad, thankyou for the information!

Comment: @NadiaPerry Before you fix, test out the vulnerability by using `x' or id = '1` as the password on your login form.