# mysql_connect : error access denied (www-data@localhost)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

i have a raspberry pi with mysql/phpMyadmin installed.

i can access to my website with my IP on internet.

http://[Ip fix not 127.0.0.1]/[site name/folder name]

html code and PHP work but...

Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
$hostname = "{IP FIX}";
$username = "********";
$password = "********";
$DataBase = "horaires";
$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($DataBase);
```

who is www-data user ?
why localhost ? i am on internet!

could you help me plz ?

Olivier

Comment: Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230729/warning-mysql-connect-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passw

Comment: Thx for answer, but this answer don't help me. I have all privileges on my database.  My remote webserver apache2 is on my raspberry pi. Not in localhost. I dont understand how to connect to my own mysql database.

Comment: Is that bit of code in your phpMyAdmin `config.inc.php`? You should have lines like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` or `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'example.com';` instead. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html and https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#config-examples for some more hints.