# mysql 'Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Tags: mysql

I noticed strange thing. I have site on php+mysql with user jewwishl. access to mysql is open from internet for user jewwish:

```
mysql> select user,host,authentication_string from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user             | host      | authentication_string                     |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| coremgr          | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| roundcube        | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| mysql.session    | localhost | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
| jewwish          | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| jewwish          | %         | *PASSWORD                                 |
| jewwishl         | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want to close it. I prohibit internet access for user jewwish in ispmanager, so I get

```
mysql> select user,host,authentication_string from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user             | host      | authentication_string                     |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| coremgr          | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| roundcube        | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| mysql.session    | localhost | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
| jewwish          | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
| jewwishl         | localhost | *PASSWORD                                 |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but if I do so I've got error "Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user 'jewwish'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". What could be a reason? What is relation of 'jewwish'@'%' with 'jewwishl'@'localhost'?

UPD here is connection code:

```
define("DB_NAME", "jewwish");
define("DB_USER", "jewwishl");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");

...
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: mysql\_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230729/warning-mysql-connect-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: @onedevteam.com no, see update